# Своя метка в яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Почему не отображается метка? Путь к картинке верный. В чем ошибка?

Ссылка на документацию по теме: http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/tasks/how-to-add-placemark.xml#placemark-style
Ссылка на сайт, где надо реализовать: http://fastnails.myjino.ru/kontakty

```
    {literal}

<div id="ymaps-map-id_134337756174430647519" style="width: 1020px; height: 396px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fid_134337756174430647519(ymaps) {
    var map = new ymaps.Map("ymaps-map-id_134337756174430647519", {
        center: [37.66324533754642, 55.84944941376199],
        zoom: 16,
        type: "yandex#map"
    });

    map.controls
        .add("zoomControl")
        .add("mapTools")
        .add(new ymaps.control.TypeSelector(["yandex#map", "yandex#satellite", "yandex#hybrid", "yandex#publicMap"]));
    map.geoObjects
      // Создает стиль
var s = new YMaps.Style();

// Создает стиль значка метки
s.iconStyle = new YMaps.IconStyle();

s.iconStyle.href = "/uploads/images/fav.png";
s.iconStyle.size = new YMaps.Point(18, 29);
s.iconStyle.offset = new YMaps.Point(-9, -29);
var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark([37.669215637163646, 55.85044779554645], {style: s});
map.addOverlay(placemark);
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?coordorder=longlat&load=package.full&wizard=constructor&lang=ru-RU&onload=fid_134337756174430647519"></script>
<!-- Этот блок кода нужно вставить в ту часть страницы, где вы хотите разместить карту (конец) -->
{/literal}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [конструктором](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/tools/constructor/), после измените размеры выводимой карты.

Comment: Мне надо отобразить картинку свою ,вместо стандартной метки.
Конструктор не поможет

Answer (score 0):

Потому что это работает для яндекс апи 1.х
А вы подключаете библиотеку 2.х